# Sidekiq perform_later enqueue after waiting time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wait, jobs, sidekiq, job-scheduling

I need to add a job to run in the background, which I can easily do by `MyJob.perform_later(args)`.

But I need some wait time before the scheduling, say 1 minute.

So if I schedule the job, it should get enqueued after 1 minute.

One workaround I could think of is to add sleep to my job.
For example:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(args)
    sleep 1.minute
    code
    more code
    more code
  end
end
```

Which enqueues it immediately but sleeps in execution(not what I am looking for).
There should be a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can set a wait option like
`MyJob.set(wait: 1.minute).perform_later`

By setting wait the job will be enqueued after 1 minute.

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job